# SQL LocalDB Nightmare

Tags: sql-server-express, localdb

I'm having some serious problems with SQL LocalDB and Express for Web 2015.

I have a number of development workstations - all of which have had Express for Web 2015 installed from the same installer version and all of the machines previously had SQL Server Express 2008 installed.

When I try to load up my solution into Express for Web then subsequently open the database file from the App_Data folder, I run into the following error:

`The database 'db1.mdf' cannot be opened because it is version 852. This server supports version 782 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported`

First and foremost, I'm unsure as to what the version `852` refers to - especially given that the versions reported by SQLLocalDB are in the form of `xx.x.xxxx.x`

I've looked at the version of LocalDB installed on my present workstation which is reporting back two versions as follows:

`where sqllocaldb`
`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\SqlLocalDb.exe`
`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\SqlLocalDb.exe`

So this has lead me to *believe* that when I run a `sqllocaldb` command, its picking up the first executable from the first directory in the list.

When I check the LocalDB info, I get the following:

`sqllocaldb info`
`MSSQLLocalDB`
`ProjectsV13`
`v11.0`
`XpoDemos`

No idea what the bottom 3 are and presumably, I don't care. If I check the info on `MSSQLLocalDB`, I get this:

`sqllocaldb info MSSQLLocalDB`
`Name: MSSQLLocalDB`
`Version: 12.0.4100.1`
`Shared Name:`
`Owner: <my user name>`
`Auto-create: Yes`
`State: running`
`Instance pipe name: np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#BF25386A\tsql\query`

Which now indicates to me that the MSSQLLocalDB instance is being created with the latest set of tools installed with Express for Web 2015 yet Express for Web cannot and will not allow me to browse the database within the environment.

Can anyone help please?